# As sentence-ending feminine particles, what is the difference between の and わ?

Tags: word-choice, particle-の, sentence-final-particles, feminine-speech

So according to Denshi Jisho, it says the following on these two particles:

- [の](https://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%AE): Indicates emotional emphasis.
- [わ](https://jisho.org/search/%E3%82%8F): Indicates emotion or admiration.

Those definitions sound similar. But there must be a difference between the two. Otherwise, there would be no need for two particles.

So, does anyone know the difference?

Comment: > "Otherwise, there would be no need for two particles." - Why not? Natural languages have tons of unneeded synonyms.

Comment: @Blavius: Oh, sorry. I guess I was just being logical. But I forgot that natural languages are not logical.

Comment: I wouldn't trust jisho, just saying...those are pretty bad explanations for the differences.

Comment: @MichealGignac (I don't come up with good explanations but) You will eventually be able to grasp it when you study about の especially because those two things are never interchangeable. Anyway, you can just forget those poor definitions.